# php : csv import to multiple table is taking too long

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

i am using csv importer library to load bulk of products into mysql database with codeigniter. csv file has some column names from one table like name, price and some column names from another table like categories. it inserts name and price to first table and categories will be inserted after we got id from first table, so category will go with id of the product. but this is taking too long to process the csv file (1000 entries = 2 minutes). the code i have put is

```
$csv_file_data = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
foreach ($csv_file_data as $csv_data) {
     $required = array(
                'name' => $csv_data['name'],
                'price' => $csv_data['price']
     );
     foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->set($key, $value);
     }
     $categories= array();
     foreach ($csv_data as $key => $value) {
                if(strstr($key, 'categories')) {
                    $category = explode('|', $value);
                    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($category); $i++) {
                        array_push($categories, $category[$i]);
                    }
                }
     }
     $this->db->insert('first_table');
     $id = $this->db->insert_id();

     foreach ($categories as $metatag) {
                    $this->db->set('productid', $id);
                    $this->db->set('category', $metatag);
                    $this->db->insert('second_table');
     }
}
```

but it is taking too long to process only 1000 entries, how to optimize this to process 5000 entries in less than 20-30 seconds ?

Comment: Move all db actions from loops. Use loops just to form(at) expected arrays (from db perspective) then after loops use insert batch.

Comment: @Tpojka still 100 entries taking 12 seconds and this is too much time.

Comment: I agree it mustn't happen. Are you sure that there is no single DB action inside this loop `foreach ($csv_file_data as $csv_data) {`?

Comment: yes there is none @Tpojka

Comment: Edit your question with new code you have there and include errors if any. Check logs both: application and system/web server logs.

Comment: there are no errors @Tpojka

Comment: So edit your question with way I proposed in my first comment. Also, you can set some variables with `microtime()` before and after each loop and that way check where is bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after ...

```
$csv_file_data = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);

foreach ($csv_file_data as $csv_data) {
    $required = array(
        'name'  => $csv_data['name'],
        'price' => $csv_data['price']
    );

    $this->db->set($required);

    $categories = array();
    foreach ($csv_data as $key => $value) {
        if (strstr($key, 'categories')) {
            $category = explode('|', $value);
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($category); $i++) {
                $categories[] = $category[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    $this->db->insert('first_table');

    $bulk = array();
    $id   = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($categories as $metatag) {
        $bulk[] = array(
            'category'  => $metatag,
            'productid' => $id,
        );          
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('table2', $bulk);
}
```

Note the use of insert_batch which will dramatically improve your speed and also you can give `set()` an array.

Comment: I have already tried this but still same time 100 rows = 10-12 secs

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a version like this and tell me if this is working and return me the time for 100 rows ?

```
$bulk          = [];
$csv_file_data = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
$required      = [];
foreach ($csv_file_data as $csv_data) {
    $bulk       = [];
    $id         = $this->db->insert_id();
    $required[] = [
        'name'  => $csv_data['name'],
        'price' => $csv_data['price'],
    ];
    foreach ($csv_data as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== strpos($key, 'categories')) {
            $category = explode('|', $value);
            foreach ($category as $metatag) {
                $bulk[] = [
                    'category'  => $metatag,
                    'productid' => $id,
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}

$this->db->insert_batch('first_table', $required);
$this->db->insert_batch('second_table', $bulk);
```

Comment: will it $id = $this->db->insert_id(); give id before inser query to first_table ?

Comment: Yes. But in the first code I saw, you only need ids before the second insertion. There are 2 little 'optimizations' there. The first with one loop removed, and the second, with a little less insertions. That's why I asked you if it was working too in your case